# How can I encrypt with a RSA private key in deno?

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption, deno

Per title, I can use `crypto` module to encrypt a content with public key like this `crypto.publicEncrypt()` in nodejs.

ref this https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer.

How can I do such thing in deno? Try to find out similar module of deno, but no luck.

Any help or suggestion is appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

I recently implemented RSA in pure TypeScript. You can use [god_crypto](https://github.com/invisal/god_crypto) (I know I have weird taste of naming the library).

```js
import { RSA } from "https://deno.land/x/god_crypto/mod.ts";

const publicKey = RSA.parseKey(`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsL3rvxnzQ3G8JjYqhUli
zCYdpwBcQR5ahk1qZAfikOHwvejLh1OeqelKuvd1Vw36R8xQmuuWPu/u2V/CRRQW
uO18dVGkmKe/SI9gwXzjRCJiFwM7F4wki7Rt7KKqydX70nzN33tARkE3obIBLPdy
OGqJjaJicDo9hFQsJ/SksizPD/BTlKa4AGyNWMcvmW7fMbeTiwDbEx3Z3sR0Opqn
5no7QJ+6UkhV32q5jgQ7Eg2AgMBnh5cN22bxu/YxNGzsRzh29yqeSPaRBRUB/K0t
TzmCXg9aKg/Xy7hyNpKdd8gi+wawBj6nxvBfCPwGN7gP4rsedM8TMX+ibsn/rID8
BQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
`);

const rsa = new RSA(publicKey)
console.log(await rsa.encrypt("Hello World"));
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am the author of the library.*

Comment: you are a good man

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there's a library similar to that in deno currently. However you could port the crypto library to typescript and use it in deno https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/crypto.js

Comment: Thanks @Keimeno. the linked module u sent is a node modules, what do u mean "port the crypto library"?  

If I didn't take wrong I should use bundle tool to extract it, right?  

I tried it with Rollup, but no lucky. Because underneath the crypto is c++ implements. I'm not sure why but I can't bundle it successfully.  

 Any suggestions?

Comment: What needs to be done to make this work is, take the node standard library crypto and rewrite it in typescript. Then it can be used in deno.

Comment: Do you mean rewrite it? It sounds a giant project...

Comment: It's not that big, mostly it's index file and some helper files https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib/internal/crypto

Comment: I saw `internalBinding` in the files. It indicates a bridge of c++ module. Just have no idea how to handle this part in deno. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I come with workaround listed below. I am not sure about security impacts, but it helps until somebody comes with support for crypto here: https://github.com/denoland/deno/tree/master/std/node/#commonjs-module-loading or build deno native crypto module (supporting not only scrypt).

**deno method**

```
import { exec, IExecResponse, OutputMode } from "https://deno.land/x/exec/mod.ts";

const passwordHasher = async (password: string, salt: string) => {
  const output: IExecResponse = await exec(
    `node ./node_scripts/pbkdf2.js --string ${password} --salt ${salt}`,
    {output: OutputMode.Capture}
  );
  return output.output;
}

export default passwordHasher;
```

**pbkdf2.js node script**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

console.log(
  crypto.pbkdf2Sync(argv.string, argv.salt, 100000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex')
);
```